# Programmatically Set Local Security Settings in Windows

Tags: windows, com, wmi, group-policy, adsi

Hello good people of Stack Overflow,

I am having a hard time trying to figure out a way to do this (or even if it is possible).  I am trying to programmatically set (not just read, which I can do just fine) Local Security settings on Windows 7.  I don't know if I'm referring to those correctly, but basically I want to change things under "Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies."

Things I have tried/researched:

- Setting group policy using IGroupPolicyObject/registry settings...I can do this for group policy in administrative templates, but security settings don't appear to have anything to do with the registry.
- Setting values using ADSI...I can't find any examples of how to set the policy for the whole computer--all I can find are examples of setting things like password expiration for specific users in AD.
- WMI--I cannot find any examples of actually setting security policy with WMI--I can read values just fine using the RSOP_ classes but those appear to be read-only.  Also, I can't seem to really figure out what exactly is available to me with WMI because there doesn't really seem to be any comprehensive documentation.

Any thoughts (or better yet, examples?)  This is driving me crazy--there seem to be 30,000 different possible ways to do this, but none of them are particularly helpfully documented and I feel like I'm drowning in alphabet soup.

Thanks!

Comment: Looked at the LSA API as well--can't seem to find any functions for setting this specific policy.  I have found the registry key affected by this as well as the format, but I really don't want to go about setting it that way...too messy.  If worst comes to worst I can just call "net" from my program, but it feels like a defeat.  Here is a link to the registry key for anyone who is interested: (http://www.beginningtoseethelight.org/ntsecurity/index.htm#BB4F910C0FFA1E43).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the settings under "Account Policies" can be configured using [`NetUserModalsSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with either [`USER_MODALS_INFO_0`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (password policy) or [`USER_MODALS_INFO_3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (account lockout policy).

However, I couldn't find any way to configure "Password must meet complexity requirements" or "Store passwords using reversible encryption".

Answer (score 0):

The way I have been doing it is using secedit.exe which is part of system32 you can do

```
Secedit.exe /export /cfg c:\cfg.txt
```